# Accuracy of IBM Watson speech recognition is low

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I develop an application that uses speech-to-text to transcribe audio to text. The accuracy is low. Some sentences have no meaning. Is there a way to improve the accuracy of speech-to-text?

Here's an example:

http://book.vidalab.co/books/alice-in-wonderland

Alice in Wonderland, in section 2:

"over at home to go white pawn this way you see ads"
should be "over at home to go white pawn this way you see Alice"

"rat in white"
should be "red and white"

"and the white army tries to win and the red on the Trice twin"
should be "and the white army tries to win and the red army tries to win"

Comment: it's not an AI. See how it handles this poem: http://www.waylink-english.co.uk/?page=16100

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to parse poems. But it's not doing so well with literature. Maybe literature is also out of bound?

Answer (score 1):

You can try different services, for example Speechmatics, it's not very good at getting speakers but words are much more accurate than from Watson, the result is like this:

```
Credits of Alice in Wonderland by Alice girs Timberg this is a box recording all of her vocal recordings are in the public domain for more information or volunteer. Please visit libber Vox dot org.
I just listed stage directions read by McKayla Curtis Lewis Carroll.
Read by Shannon Brown Alice read by Amanda Friday the Red Queen read by Shauna canat White Queen read by Elizabeth Klatt White Rabbit read by Todd Humpty Dumpty read by Jeff Machado written read by Brett Hirsch.
The Mock Turtle read by Ted the alarm Mad Hatter read by Elliot gage the March Hare by Charlotte Duckett's dormouse read by Kimberly Krauss frog read by Larry Wilson Duchess read by L.A. Cheshire Cat read by Sarah Herschell Tweedle-Dee read.
By Charlotte Brown.
Do you do do I read by the sea a solo the King of Hearts read by Ted alarm the Queen of Hearts read by eating Ray Headrick knave by glorious Joe Carter pillar back at 2 loss to spot read by Dave Harris.
Five Spot read by Dave Harith. Seven of spades read by Dave Hereth end of credits.
```

Surnames recognition is very complex task, not many companies are doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major parts in any STT system: acoustic model and language model. The first one is about audio and speaker and handles things like: noise, pronunciations, accents and so on. Language Model is about structure of a given language and the words used in the speech.

If you would like to test an STT, use the recordings which are as close as possible to your target speech. A system which performs very well for general speech, or, for example, medical transcription, may be not a good in handle speech about archeology or poetry.e